# Automatically set cross-sell based on product category (WooCommerce)

Tags: woocommerce

I would like if someone can help add to this snippet below, to limit how many products are shown as cross sells. The snippet works nearly perfectly, but it does not limit how many products are shown (which can create literally hundreds of products to be shown in cross-sells depending on your shop size).

PS - Kudos to the person who originally created this snippet in another post.

```
function my_cart_crosssell_ids( $cross_sells, $cart ) {

    // Set emtpy array
    $product_cats_ids = array();
    $product_cats_ids_unique = array();

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {       
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Get current product categories id(s) & add to array
        $product_cats_ids = array_merge( $product_cats_ids, wc_get_product_term_ids( $product_id, 'product_cat' ) );
    }

    // Not empty
    if ( !empty( $product_cats_ids ) ) {
        // Removes duplicate values
        $product_cats_ids_unique = array_unique( $product_cats_ids, SORT_REGULAR );

        // Get product id(s) from a certain category, by category-id
        $product_ids_from_cats_ids = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $product_cats_ids_unique,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                )
            ),
        ) );

        // Removes duplicate values
        $cross_sells = array_unique( $product_ids_from_cats_ids, SORT_REGULAR );
    }

    return $cross_sells;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_crosssell_ids', 'my_cart_crosssell_ids', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi @ 7uc1f3r. Firstly thanks for pulling me up on how to properly credit the author and not duplicating an existing question. Secondly thanks for replying so quickly with the information about the woocommerce_cross_sells_total filter hook.

Comment: I literally added the woocommerce_cross_sells_total filter hook straight after the previous snippet you created, and it seems to work perfectly. Thank you!